# d3.js force layout - filter and restoring nodes by attribute

Tags: d3.js

I have been struggling with this issue for a long time with very little progress. I was going to put my code up here but it becomes quite long and convoluted and I'm still not sure I am even taking the correct approach so I thought backing up, showing the data and saying what I want to accomplish would be a approach to take.

Basically my goal is to create a d3 force layout. All data will be 'hard coded' into the page. I have done some network analysis on the nodes and have included those metrics in the dataset (eigenvector, betweeness, etc.) I want to be able to create the network vis, and have sliders that I can use to filter the network down by the various metrics. In other words I have a range slider that is set to the min and max of the network's “degree” metric (as an example) and as I adjust the slider values the network filters the nodes that fall outside those values. I want to be able to filter these nodes out and back in.

I've seen a number of examples of filtering and most are concerned with reducing the network and don't speak to the restoring the nodes. My attempts have resulted in either nothing happening, or multiple copies of existing nodes being created, or any number of behaviors, but not what I'm after. There is so many ways to 'skin the cat' in d3 that I keep going down paths that don't allow me (or I'm just not able to understand) to control the filtering the way I want.

I don't want to just control the visibility, I want the nodes to be removed and restored completely, and for the network to readjust smoothly.

Here is a sample of the data that I am using ...

```
var dataset = {
  “directed”: false, 
  “graph”: [], 
  “nodes”: [
    {
    “category”: “new”, 
    “eigen”: 0.05923, 
    “between”: 0.0, 
    “close”: 0.25265, 
    “deg”: 1, 
    “id”: “Name1”, 
    “uid”: 100006190145565
    }, 
    {
    “category”: “known”, 
    “eigen”: 0.00411, 
    “between”: 0.002002792177543483, 
    “close”: 0.19151, 
    “deg”: 3, 
    “id”: “Name2”, 
    “uid”: 100002598631097
    }, 
    {
    “category”: “new”, 
    “eigen”: 0.0, 
    “between”: 0.0, 
    “close”: 0.06203, 
    “deg”: 1, 
    “id”: “Name3”, 
    “uid”: 727631862
    }, 
    {
    “category”: “new”, 
    “eigen”: 0.00725, 
    “between”: 0.0, 
    “close”: 0.21037, 
    “deg”: 1, 
    “id”: “Name4”, 
    “uid”: 100008585823128
    }, 
], 
“links”: [
    {
    “source”: 0, 
    “target”: 1
    }, 
    {
    “source”: 0, 
    “target”: 1
    }, 
    {
    “source”: 0, 
    “target”: 3
    }
], 
“multigraph”: false
};
```

I can supply some of my code as well, but I think it would simply muddy the discussion as I have tried multiple approaches, none of which worked well, each of which just seemed to confuse me further when I would achieve partial results. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.